# Mouse stops working when lifted and put down back, takes 1-3 secs to work again

Tags: windows-7, laptop, mouse

I bought [this](http://www.dynexproducts.com/products/computer-accessories/DX-PMSE.html) mouse in 2010, and since then, I have already used it on a lot of different computers.

Last month, I got a Samsung ultrabook with Windows 7 Home Premium, and I'm facing a problem which is driving me CRAZY.

My USB HID-compliant mouse (the dynex one), simply stops working when I lift it up and put it down back on the table. After I return it to the table, it takes like 1-3 seconds to back working.

I can also hear that Windows' sound when you unplug an USB device (lift), and the sound of plugging a new USB device (putting back to the table). After the sound, it backs to work, only after the sound.

After a research, I found Windows could be possibly disabling the USB to save battery of my notebook when I lift it, because Windows could find it's not being used anymore.

I already disallowed my windows to turn off USB Root Hub to save power ([here](https://superuser.com/a/66467/169684)).
And I also already disabled the "USB selective suspend setting" (both "on battery" and "plugged in" on Control Panel\Power Options\Advanced power settings).

Someone knows anything else I can do to solve this?
I already switched some mices I have here, and the problem refuses to stop.

Comment: Just so I understand what you're saying in the last paragraph: You've tried this with mulitple mouses(mice) and had the same problem happen?  Have you tried using different USB ports?  If so, does the problem still happen?

Comment: If you go to Control Panel / Mouse / Hardware / Properties / Driver, is the the "Roll Back Driver" button greyed out ?

Comment: @harrymc the [Roll Back Driver] button is disabled

Comment: Ensure that there's no uncheckable "Allow the computer to disable this device to save power" box in Device Manager for the entries under "Mice and other pointing devices" and "Human Interface Devices."

Comment: try installing mouse drivers/software...
microsoft(intellipoint) and logitech mices come with ones...i don't which brand is yours..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that the "Roll Back Driver" button is disabled means that you are still using the original generic Windows driver. However, Dynex does not supply a driver for this mouse, so you have no choice about it.

Some ideas to try :

First, ensure that you are totally patched-up in Windows Update, including optional updates.

Second, if you have a touchpad, make sure you have the latest drivers
and try to "Disable internal pointing device when external USB pointing device is attached",
similar to the way this is done in [this article](http://seoroot.com/blog/computing/hardware/how-to-auto-disable-touchpad-on-synaptics.html), if this does apply to the touchpad software
on your computer.

Another idea is to go into the Device Manager, locate your mouse and delete it. Delete also any other displayed mouse. Then unplug the mouse, reboot and re-plug it. Create a system restore point just in case before you start. Let me know if this changes anything.

Answer (score 3):

The cable is likely intermittent. It loses connection at one angle, and then connection is restored when you put it back to it's old angle. To confirm this, try another mouse in the same port. If that works, it's likely your mouse that is broken. Another test you could do is lift your mouse and the mouse-pad at the same time, if it breaks, then it's the cable, if no, then maybe there is something to your auto-disable theory after all.

Comment: I agree with Jikag, sounds like there is a bad connection somewhere, especially if you are hearing the USB connect/disconnect sound. Since I like to tinker with things I would open it up and see if you can't fix it yourself with some electrical tape or something.

Comment: Also try same mouse in another port or another computer.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with my G9x Logitech mouse; lift it up, stops working for about a second or two.  Drove me nuts.  My last resort was to blow into the laser hole in the bottom of the mouse, and it seemed to have worked.  Looks like it was just some dirt/dust particles on my mouse.  Try it, it may work for you too.

Comment: Thank you! This just worked for my Microsoft Sculpt Comfort mouse, after opening it up and blasting it with compressed air.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same identical problem with the Logitech MX Mouse M-R0001 (I have 3 of them). I noticed that when lifting the Mouse off of the desk/mouse pad (when/if using one) it disconnects, no matter how high/low and how gently I lift it, it disconnects. I switched out the little receiver and the same scenario played out.

I tried the other two mice (same exact models) and the same scenario played out only on 1 of the 2 mice. This seems to tell me there's some hardware issue, potentially something loose inside....not sure, but seems hardware related.

These two mice worked for a few years without this issue. After use and potential wear and tear seems to be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. If I play with the wire while moving the mouse around, I don't get the problem, although if I use the mouse on the arm of my chair, it seems to freeze up for a few seconds. I have to lift it up before it starts working again. If the problem occurs too soon after, the laser just shuts off until I unplug/plug. I guess I need a mouse pad..

Comment: Please don't leave answers stating that you have the same problem as the one described in the question. If you have sufficient reputation, [you may upvote](https://superuser.com/privileges/vote-up) the question. Alternatively, "star" it as a favorite and you will be notified of any new answers.