# Roccat Kone XTD gaming mouse disconnect when lifted

Tags: usb, drivers, mouse, gaming

**Device:**

[Roccat Kone XTD Gaming Mouse](http://www.roccat.org/en-US/Products/Gaming-Mice/Kone-XTD-Series/Kone-XTD/)

*Wired gaming mouse

**Problem:**

If I lift the mouse just above the mouse pad or higher the mouse disconnects the *tracking laser*(if that what it is called). All the other buttons on it are working, scroll wheel, left, right click, special buttons, lights etc. The mouse doesn't respond to movement.

To make the *tracking laser* work again I have to reconnect the mouse to the usb port.

I see others have had some similar problems,[Mouse stops working when lifted and put down back, takes 1-3 secs to work again](https://superuser.com/questions/499111/mouse-stops-working-when-lifted-and-put-down-back-takes-1-3-secs-to-work-again)[USB mouse disconnecting and reconnecting in windows and linux](https://superuser.com/questions/611161/usb-mouse-disconnecting-and-reconnecting-in-windows-and-linux) but they don't have the same stuff as I do and their fixes doesn't work for me.

**How long have it been like this?**

I have had this mouse for years now, it wasn't like this before. It might have been a year after I bought it that it started to do act crazy. And I probably have had it for 3 years now. It's annoying when I play games because I tend to reposition the mouse often.

It acts the same on all 3 computers I have tried it on. OS X , windows 7 and another windows 10.

I have primary used this mouse on my stationary pc running Windows 7.

**Fixes?**

1. I have reinstalled the drivers multiple times over the years.
2. Different usb ports, also on other computers. Same behavior.
3. Tried cleaning the "laser"
4. Tried installing Adobe Reader...
5. A few years ago I sendt an email to Roccat...they never responded(new mail is sendt..)

**Question**

What can be the possible failures here?

What can I do to find out whats wrong?

Can it be fixed and how?

Comment: Get a new mouse.  Your actions have confirmed the problem is the mouse and none of the USB Hosts you have attached it to.

Comment: I was hoping for not so expensive tips...

Comment: Superuser is for pratical questions.  When you indicate you have tried other hardware, and the behavior remained the same across all those devices, the only conclusion is the hardware itself is bad.  Superuser isn't the place to come for "tips", its for pratical questions, that can be answered with partical answers.

Comment: Did you inspect the optics under your mouse? Did you try to clean the optics gently?

Comment: yes. All clean and looking good.

Comment: Sounds like a faulty laser sensor. I've not experienced this particular issue with any of my Roccat mice, but you'll probably need to replace the mouse. Also, when contacting support, use the online contact form at http://www.roccat.org/en-US/Support/Support-Form/ (or the equivalent in your country) rather than sending them an email directly; I did this to get a Kone XTD with faulty DPI buttons replaced under warranty.

Comment: The Roccat mice use some over-intelligent surface texture recognition and distance optimization algorithms. From the problem description it looks like this algorithm is now broken. However, I can't imagine any mechanism how a mouse firmware can deteriorate to that degree, unless the actual algorithm is implemented in host driver, and some system incompatibilities prevent the smooth working of the algorithm..

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be with the laser itself or perhaps the firmware that 'drives' the mouse.

Option 1) Download newest up-to-date mouse firmware drivers from the Roccat website: http://www.roccat.org/en-US/Support/Downloads/  [most likely your issue]

Option 2) Try recreating the issue with the mouse plugged into a different USB port(play with 2.0/3.0 ports)

Option 3) The hardware (laser) inside of the mouse is faulty and needs to replaced. If you've owned it for as long as you have you have probably exceeded the warranty terms, so it may be time to grab a new one.

It could be fixed, if you have one of those circuit-drawing pens, you could theoretically disassemble the mouse, find the circuit that has lost it's connection on the circuit board and re-draw the circuit. I have seen this work on old keyboards, but I have never tried a mouse. That may be a good route to go if it doesn't seem it can be repaired in any other fashion.

Link for circuit pen: [https://www.amazon.com/Circuit-Scribe-Conductive-Ink-Pen/dp/B00OZATJ3A](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00OZATJ3A)

Best of luck!

Comment: Tried new firmware, tried different ports. Hardware functions fine as long as I keep it on the mouse pad, but if I lift the mouse just a little bit, the laser seem to disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

Try powered USB hub. Many times there is an issue with the driver/os/mobo not supplying correct or consistent amperage.

Comment: Tried with a D-Link hub. Didn't work. Probably end up bying a new mouse.