# My mouse is disconnecting/reconnecting

Tags: mouse

I had a Logitech G9 and my mouse kept disconnecting/reconnecting after a few seconds randomly. So I changed back to my MX518 and didn't have the problem for at least a month. Then it started again. Right now I just had a disconnection/reconnection every 5 seconds for an entire minute.

I've looked into Device Manager and everytime the disconnection was happening it was refreshing. I tried turning off the power management off all the USB Root Hub. I don't know what to do anymore.

Here's a screenshot of my device manager : 
[image]

EDIT: And I've also tried the mouses on other computers and they work fine. I'm on windows 7 64 bits.

Comment: I've had both of these mice before do this same thing until they eventually don't reconnect back. My difference was I saw this across several machines. Keep in mind that these devices, especially the mx518, have been known to have these issues over time.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem for over 6 months and just found my solution here tonight.
I have read many people guessing on various posts around the net, including
compromises to the mouse cable. Yet my Logitech MX518 worked fine on my roommate's
older WinVista computer.

This superuser.com post gave me the extended answer.
[Why is my USB mouse disconnecting and reconnecting randomly and often?](https://superuser.com/questions/53740/why-is-my-usb-mouse-disconnecting-and-reconnecting-randomly-and-often/66467#66467)

Basically, go into Device Manager, open the USB Controller section, delete all of the "USB Root Hub" by uninstalling them (*I had two instances; some people have more.)

It was a little tricky to delete the 2nd one since my mouse ceased working after deleting the 1st instance.  Reboot the computer and Win7 re-installs the standard driver (the USB Root Hub).  These were the only 2 fixes I needed for a months-long frustrating problem.

Answer (score 0):

To Diagnose -

Connect the mouse directly to a USB port on the PC. If the issue goes away, it is a problem with the hub. (keep in mind that USB connections have a max combined power draw before things start to get wonky).

If the mouse continues to exhibit the issue when connected directly to a USB port on the PC, then you should refresh the drivers and even replace batteries.