# Random mouse freezing

Tags: windows-7, usb, mouse, freeze

My mouse (mice actually, tried two different mice) frequently freezes, and becomes unresponsive. Sometimes I hear the Windows unplugging sound (as if I removed the mouse from my USB port) and sometimes it continues working after a few seconds.

However, whenever I unplug and plug it back in everything continues working. I haven't changed my PC settings for years and I'm somewhat worried that my motherboard might be failing me.

I am running Windows 7 Home Premium 64bit OS. The mice I tried are completely unrelated, one is a Razer Lachesis and another one is some rubbish Microsoft mouse. However one thing that was different was that the Razer one freezes much more frequently and never recovers.

To solve the problem myself I tried plugging the mice into different USB ports, checked if the mouse registry was valid, disabled "Enhance pointer precision" in the control panel.

Any help?

Thank you

EDIT:

I forgot to mention, when the freeze occurs, the light of the mouse begins blinking at regular intervals. Additionally, if I left click or right click the mouse, the light turns on and stays on, but it doesn't help with getting the mouse working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my USB mouse disconnecting and reconnecting randomly and often?](http://superuser.com/questions/53740/why-is-my-usb-mouse-disconnecting-and-reconnecting-randomly-and-often)

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply. The suggested Power Management solution is not applicable for me, since it is grayed out (can't be even checked at all).

Comment: What about the registry corruption answer?

Comment: How old is the mouse?  And is there tension on the cord?  It could be just the wires are broken and it is losing connection.  Switch the mouse with another computer and see if it still does the same thing.

Comment: @NelsonChan Both mice are fine and working on other computers.

Comment: Wow! It seems like both of my mice are working perfectly fine after I uninstalled the USB roots from the device managers and had them installed again after a reboot. Thank you very very much.

Comment: My happiness was very short lived :(

As soon as I replugged my old mouse (the good Razer mouse) bad stuff started happening again. Could the mouse somehow be "corrupting" the device interface?

Comment: might be obvious but have you installed the latest drivers for the mice? could be a corrupt driver causing these issues

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get partial relief for about two days by using a USB to PS/2 connector and plugging it into the unused PS/2 port, but it  started again.  The change to the PS/2 option appears to be more stable then with a straight USB connection.

I used the Device Manager to set the options for all of the USB Hubs to disable the Power Management option to "Allow the computer to disable this device to save power".

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problem and it was too annoying. Finally I have solved this problem by myself.

I just physically opened up the machine, removed the dust from each part of the laptop including Motherboard and USB ports AND voila, the problem is resolved permanently.

Previously I tried:-
1. driver update and reinstallation
2. bought new external mouse
3. mouse settings in control panel
4. power settings in device manager and control panel
5. Antivirus scan for whole computer for viruses or malware
6. reinstalled fresh OS,

BUT NOTHING WORKED and I once did dusting, it is working fine.