# Odd, “ghost failure” random USB mouse disconnects

Tags: keyboard, windows-10, mouse, usb-2

Like a month ago while playing Counter-Strike: Global Offensive my mouse just randomly disconnected and reconnected a few times, for a few moments, then disconnected.
I was using exactly the same PC between exactly the same conditions, the same devices, same op system, no settings were changed...

Than it started to get worse, my keyboard also followed my mouse and not only in Counter-Strike: Global Offensive but in windows, browsing youtube, or just my folders on my computer!

When i am using a Traktor Kontrol S2, which is also connected by USB port, sometimes it all stops, like it was frozen, i unplug it, then replug it in another, or the same USB port, and it all goes fine again, sometimes for minutes, sometimes longer...

The thing is, that it SEEMS to me that i have random disconnections, but there has to be a broken hardware, or a software which makes these things happen. I also thought about electricity problem, this is the only thing i havent checked yet, but everything else, i tried:

- new op system (different one from the previous)
- new motherboard
- checking the mouse and keyboard with another pc
- new power supply
- checking settings in windows, BIOS

What else can i check before selling my pc piece by piece, and rebuild it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: USB port having problems? Either it's worn or out-of-spec enough that the connection can be randomly lost, or there's a broken wire, or something like that. Just a guess, but maybe something to check.

Comment: Sometimes when too many devices are on the same USB controller, it will exhaust the available power for devices causing some to reset.  Sometimes the "culprit" is not the same device as the "victims."  Try removing devices or moving them to a separate USB controller (if you have more than one) to see if you can narrow it down to a particular device or combination.  Viewing devices by connection in device manager may be helpful for determining which ports are on which controllers.  Game controllers with vibration or other USB-powered motorized peripherals are prime suspects.

Answer (score 0):

**What to try**

- Put the DJ board on a separate port, connected directly to the computer!
- Check you have the latest version of the driver
- Unplug whatever is disconnecting and plug it back in again
- Try resetting you machine by shutting it down, turning it off at the socket, pressing the power button and then power on at the plug and start your machine back up
- Try a different port
- Try a different mouse, keyboard
- Try using the same mouse, keyboard on a different computer/laptop/phone.
- Check if the device has a driver from the manufacturer (Windows)
- Try using a different power outlet in a different room
- Check if the device has a driver from the manufacturer (Windows)
- If you are using a USB hub then try moving that to a different port
- Try removing the hub entirely
- Try unplugging everything else from your PC than the monitor and the mouse, or the keyboard.
- Try resetting UEFI/BIOS settings to factory settings
- Try reinstalling your operating system (on Windows: Settings > Update and Recovery > Reset) (especially if you replaced the motherboard)
- When it is installed, do not install every program at once. Ideally test after each program installation, or a small group of installations, that the devices are working properly. In case a program is interfering with the OS or devices.

Comment: try looking at http://superuser.com/questions/53740/why-is-my-usb-mouse-disconnecting-and-reconnecting-randomly-and-often?rq=1 if all else fails and you are on Windows