# Windows 8.1 keeps disconnecting from android devices from usb

Tags: windows-8.1, usb, android

I have Lenovo Z50 with Windows 8.1 it has 2 usb 2.0 and 1 usb 3.0 ports. All of the usb ports keeps disconnecting from android devices, I have tried different cables with 4 different android devices on all of three ports and every time it kept disconnecting and reconnecting. Other usb devices such as thumb drives or wireless mouse usb connector work as intended. It seems problem is isolated with android devices only. How can I solve it?

Note: When I bought my computer was working properly, I am not sure what changed but problem started a few months after I bought the computer.

Comment: See if in the BIOS, section USB Configuration, you can find XHCI Mode - if set as Smart Auto or Auto, then disable it. Try also in Power Options -> Change plan setting -> Change advanced power setting -> USB settings to disable USB selective suspend.

Comment: What android device u have?

Comment: I have tested on Samsung Galaxy S6, Samsung Galaxy S5, Nexus 4, LG G2.

Comment: @harrymc there is no USB Configuration section on BIOS. I tried Power Options before, no luck.

Comment: @Tony Do you have any Android USB drivers installed? If you do, you may want to try uninstalling them and connect your phone again. Also [try this](http://superuser.com/a/66467/167187).

Comment: when disconnected, does your Android still charge its battery? If No then it's an electrical problem with your hardware (laptop or phone) and not with Windows itself.

Comment: @Sanny yes it still charges.

Comment: @Vinayak I uninstalled them and reinstalled unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: OK. As soon as you connect, try to catch in your Android notification bar the option `Connected as Media` so you'll change it from `Media Device MTP` to `Camera PTP` or, if available, the `Mass Storage`. See if you still can find your device in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your device mini-port is faulty. Its quite common in these devices.

Comment: it was already working when I bought the computer also other usb devices working properly.