# My mouse, just says Microsoft on the bottom, and doesn't work

Tags: usb, mouse, battery

I changed the mouse batteries a few days ago and the mouse has not been working.  I don't know the specific model or type of mouse.  It is wireless and there is a USB connector in my computer.  The light is on at the bottom of my mouse.  I just don't know what the issue is.  I have tried taking the batteries out and putting them back in, turning it off and on, and taking out the wireless connector USB.  I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: I guess with no info, nobody will be able to help you. Wireless devices should have a FCC ID, I guess that would already help.

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Anything in logs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my USB mouse disconnecting and reconnecting randomly and often?](https://superuser.com/questions/53740/why-is-my-usb-mouse-disconnecting-and-reconnecting-randomly-and-often)

Answer (score 2):

There are several things which could be broken.  The USB port, the USB dongle, the wireless mouse itself.  To test, you will need another simple device which uses the same batteries, a wired USB mouse, and easy access to the ports.

Ensure that the "new" batteries work in another device.  A little flashlight is a good test.  Also ensure that in the problem mouse, the batteries are pointed in the right direction, so that plus matches with plus.

Some wireless mice operate on frequencies that are easily blocked.  Try putting the mouse very close to the USB dongle and see if its movements are received.

There may be a mating procedure for the mouse and USB dongle.  You will need to find the precise make/model to figure this out.

Open Device Manager.  Expand the "Mice and other pointing devices" section.  Plug in the wired mouse.  The list should add an entry.  Try unplugging the USB dongle.  The list should remove an entry.  It's possible for individual USB ports to work with some devices but not with others, so trying switching them around until all the USB devices are recognized.  Rebooting may help.  If the wired mouse shows up in every port, but the USB dongle does not, then the USB dongle is broken and you must buy another.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the batteries means that you already had problems with the mouse.

The problem was not with the battery (if the new batteries are correct),
so it is in the mouse itself, which nobody will agree to repair.
No one repairs mice, since the reparation will cost more than a new mouse.

Time for a new mouse.